# About the EKG and why it's waves are positive or negative.e

Tags: electricity, vectors

So, I understand that the EKG is a way of measuring the electroactivity that happens in the heart through the vectors that are created by it. 
Every cardiomyocyte has the ability to change its membrane potential.  During phase 4, in which the muscle is relaxed, the interior of the cell is negative and the exterior positive compared to it. During phase 0, there's a depolarization of the cell that makes the exterior negative (compared to the nearby exterior and to the interior of the cell) which would create a vector as we would have an area depolarized next to an area polarized. When we say polarized or depolarized we are talking from the interior of the cell point of view. 
However, as I understand it, the EKG measures what happens in the extracellular fluid, outside the cell. So let's just pretend that there's a depolarization in a cell on the far left, we would have something like this in the exterior:
- - - + + + + + + + + + + + + + + 
So theoretically, as vectors are drawn in the direction of the negatively charged side, we would have a vector pointing that way <----- 
However, it is known that vectors point the other way around on the EKG.. For example: When the atria depolarize, it happens from the right to the left atrium, which would be represented as + + + - - - - - - - - , however, the EKG sensor located in the left side of our body represents this as a positive wave.. Is it just convention (and in reality, it is a negative vector) or is there another reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

The electric potential vector should have positive magnitude in the same direction as the EKG sensor vector to have positive dot product (what you see as a positive wave).

Assuming that the EKG sensor vector goes from right to left, and considering the info you have given us about left atrium having more positive electric potential when EKG shows positive wave, I would conclude that the EKG machine considers negative electric potential as negative and vice versa. So there does not seem to be any aspect to the sign convention that is "unconventional".